# Moving an SVG mask

Tags: html, svg

I've got some SVG that I've put together, but one of the things I'm stuggling with is to move a mask that I've created. It's easiest to describe with an example:

```js
function createFog(imageUrl) {
  const mapImage = new Image();

  mapImage.onload = function() {
    // Grab the dimensions of the map
    const width = this.width;
    const height = this.height;

    d3.selectAll(".full-size").attr({
      height,
      width
    });
    d3.select("#map").attr("xlink:href", imageUrl);
  };

  mapImage.src = imageUrl;
}
createFog("https://oneinchsquare.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/greenest_transparent_grid.jpg");
```

```css
img, svg, canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
}

#interaction {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#light {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#fog {
    opacity: 0;
    fill: black;
}

.explore-outline {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #aaa;
}

.torch-outline {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ff9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="full-size">
        <g id="view" transform="scale(0.25)">
            <defs>
              <radialGradient id="radGrad" class="full-size" r="0.31">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black" />
                <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#aaa" />
                <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#bbb" />
                <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#ccc" />
                <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#ddd" />
                <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#eee" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
              </radialGradient>
              <mask class="full-size" id="explored">
                    <rect class="full-size" id="unexplored" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="white"/>
                    <g id="explored"></g>
              </mask>
              <mask id="hole">
                <rect id="mask" class="full-size" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="url(#radGrad)"></rect>
              </mask>
            </defs>
            <image class="full-size" id="map" x="0" y="0"/>
            <rect class="full-size" id="light" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" mask="url(#hole)"></rect>
            <rect class="full-size" id="fog" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" mask="url(#explored)"></rect>
        </g>
        <rect id="interaction" class="full-size" x="0" y="0"></rect>
      </svg>
```

What I wish to be able to do is to move the "light" effect when someone clicks on the background, moving the lighting to that point. This light effect is actually created by cutting a hole in the middle of a dark layer. I don't need help with the code from that point of view, it's more the things I've tried to do in SVG don't seem to produce the effect I want.

The problem I've got is I don't seem to be able to move the `radialGradient`, I assumed I could set the `cx` or `cy` but they don't seem to do anything.

This leaves me with another option that I've tried - translating the `#mask` or `#light` elements, however doing so then leaves a portion of the map uncovered. I thought I'd be able to just oversize these layers to compensate - but then unfortunately that scales the hole to larger which I don't want to do.

Is there anyway I can move this "hole" effectively?

Comment: Show us your non-working code.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau there is no code required on top of what is provided. I've been modifying SVG via DevTools to try and achieve what I want. The question is supposed to be centered on how to achieve this via SVG.  I've removed the extra auto tags that probably added confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assumed I could set the cx or cy but they don't seem to do anything.

It seems to work fine when the `cx` and `cy` are changed.

```js
function createFog(imageUrl) {
  const mapImage = new Image();

  mapImage.onload = function() {
    // Grab the dimensions of the map
    const width = this.width;
    const height = this.height;

    d3.selectAll(".full-size").attr({
      height,
      width
    });
    d3.select("#map").attr("xlink:href", imageUrl);
  };

  mapImage.src = imageUrl;
}
createFog("https://oneinchsquare.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/greenest_transparent_grid.jpg");
```

```css
img, svg, canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
}

#interaction {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#light {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#fog {
    opacity: 0;
    fill: black;
}

.explore-outline {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #aaa;
}

.torch-outline {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ff9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="full-size">
        <g id="view" transform="scale(0.25)">
            <defs>
              <radialGradient id="radGrad" class="full-size" r="0.31"
                              cx="0.3" cy="0.7">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black" />
                <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#aaa" />
                <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#bbb" />
                <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#ccc" />
                <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#ddd" />
                <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#eee" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
              </radialGradient>
              <mask class="full-size" id="explored">
                    <rect class="full-size" id="unexplored" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="white"/>
                    <g id="explored"></g>
              </mask>
              <mask id="hole">
                <rect id="mask" class="full-size" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="url(#radGrad)"></rect>
              </mask>
            </defs>
            <image class="full-size" id="map" x="0" y="0"/>
            <rect class="full-size" id="light" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" mask="url(#hole)"></rect>
            <rect class="full-size" id="fog" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" mask="url(#explored)"></rect>
        </g>
        <rect id="interaction" class="full-size" x="0" y="0"></rect>
      </svg>
```

Comment: I've been looking into this again. I hadn't realised that `cx` and `cy` are essentially a percentage of the full width/height that the mask is being applied to.

Comment: They use `objectBoundingBox` units by default.  If you want to use user space units, then add `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` to the `<radialGradient>` tag.